# Getting name of object which is using currently a script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm creating GameObjects dynamically during runtime a game. Every of them has another name bust the same script. I'm looking for way to get to know which GameObject run a script and get this information in another script.

Objects are created here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < w.wHowManyWords; i++)
    {
        var obj = new GameObject();
        obj.name = w.wLevelWords[i, 0];
        elementName = obj.name;
...
    }
```

I'd like to get information about which object started this script:

```
public class ClickAction : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    private string[,] levelWords;

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("I am here");
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you just say `print(gameObject.name)`?

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for that! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[code11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595277/getting-name-of-object-which-is-using-curently-a-script-in-unity#comment68426168_40595277) already answered but if you want more control you can use this:

```
Debug.Log(gameObject.name, gameObject);
```

when you click on log message in console window it will highlight the object in hierarchy.